# Need help to changing the script

Tags: batch-file

I need help to change the script by Hackoo which I found by this link.

[batch file that searches for strings in a text file inside all files in folders/subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40571000/batch-file-that-searches-for-strings-in-a-text-file-inside-all-files-in-folders/50727465#50727465)

The script is good, but in the log instead of the search text, it produces the numbers in parentheses.

For example, I'm looking for the text "My_Cat" which is in the file textlist.txt. The script found a file in which was "My_Cat", but after the end of the search it gives the number in brackets instead of "My_Cat". When creating a log the same thing. Really? Does number search the text? 0_0

In short, I need to instead that "[1] - Test_Dog.xml -- "D:\Files\Test_Dog.xml" to was it "[My_Cat] - Test_Dog -- "D:\Files\Test_Dog.xml"

Comment: The linked code is [tag:batch-file], not [tag:autoit]. The current tag is notifying the incorrect people to help.

Comment: I'm aware, but the site told me to add one of the popular tags and batch-file among them absent. But if someone can make the same script on autoit, then I will only be for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
; AutoIt Version:   3.3.10.2 or later.
; Author:           Michael Heath
; Script Function:  Searches files for strings in recursive mode using findstr.

#pragma compile(Out, 'searcher.exe')
#pragma compile(FileVersion, 3.3.10.2)
#pragma compile(ProductVersion, 1.1.0.0)
#pragma compile(FileDescription, 'Searcher')
#pragma compile(ProductName, 'Searcher')
#pragma compile(Console, False)

#region - Generated Constants
; If Std includes added cause error with these,
; then remove any of these constants to fix.
Global Const $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE = -3
Global Const $GUI_CHECKED = 1
Global Const $GUI_UNCHECKED = 4
Global Const $GUI_ENABLE = 64
Global Const $GUI_DISABLE = 128
#endregion

; Get the search executable for main use.
$sSearchExe = _Get_SearchExe()

#region - CmdlineSwitch
If $CMDLINE[0] Then
    ; Patterns file
    $sStringsFile = ''
    ; i.e *.txt
    $sFilePatterns = ''
    ; Directory to search from.
    $sSearchPath = ''
    ; Output with filenames and search strings.
    $bWithNoStrings = False

    For $i = 1 To $CMDLINE[0]
        Switch $CMDLINE[$i]
            Case '/?'
                MsgBox(0x40000, 'Searcher Help', _
                 'Searches files for strings in recursive mode using findstr.' & @CRLF & @CRLF & _
                 'Syntax: ' & @ScriptName & ' search_path patternfile filepattern [[filepattern] ... ] [/m]' & @CRLF & _
                 @CRLF & _
                 'Arguments are:' & @CRLF _
                 & @CRLF & 'search_path' _
                 & @CRLF & @TAB & 'Directory path to search from.' _
                 & @CRLF & 'patternfile' _
                 & @CRLF & @TAB & 'Gets search strings from the specified file.' _
                 & @CRLF & 'filepattern' _
                 & @CRLF & @TAB & 'File to search for i.e. *.txt.' _
                 & @CRLF & '/m' _
                 & @CRLF & @TAB & 'Output files and no strings.' _
                 & @CRLF & @TAB & 'Only works with findstr.' _
                 & @CRLF & @CRLF & _
                 'No arguments passed shows the Gui.' & @CRLF & @CRLF & _
                 'Arguments passed may require a command to get stdout i.e a CMD for loop. ' & _
                 'Or pipe to more i.e. command|more. If compiled as console then ' & _
                 'getting the stdout should be like using a console executable.' & @CRLF & @CRLF & _
                 'An ini file can be used named "searcher.ini" in the program directory i.e.' & @CRLF & @CRLF & _
                 ' [main]' & @CRLF & _
                 ' SearchExe=findstr' & @CRLF & @CRLF & _
                 'You can use "SearchExe=strings" or "SearchExe=strings64" ' & _
                 'which are available from Windows Sysinternals.' _
                )
                Exit

            Case Else
                If $CMDLINE[$i] == '/m' Then
                    $bWithNoStrings = True
                ElseIf $sSearchPath == '' Then
                    $sSearchPath = $CMDLINE[$i]
                ElseIf $sStringsFile == '' Then
                    $sStringsFile = $CMDLINE[$i]
                Else
                    $sFilePatterns &= '"' & $CMDLINE[$i] & '" '
                EndIf
        EndSwitch
    Next

    $sFilePatterns = StringTrimRight($sFilePatterns, 1)

    If $sFilePatterns == '' Or $sSearchPath == '' Or $sStringsFile == '' Then
        ConsoleWriteError('Incorrect arguments passed' & @CRLF)
        Exit 1
    EndIf

    $sStdout = _Run_Search($sFilePatterns, $sSearchPath, $sStringsFile, $bWithNoStrings)

    ; Trim ends of whitespace and output to stdout.
    $sStdout = StringStripWS($sStdout, 3)
    ConsoleWrite($sStdout & @CRLF)
    Exit
EndIf
#endregion

$iMainGui = GUICreate('Searcher', 640, 580)
GUICtrlCreateLabel('Path to search', 10, 10)
$iSearchPath = GUICtrlCreateInput('', 10, 30, 500)
GUICtrlCreateLabel('File patterns', 10, 60)
$iFilePatterns = GUICtrlCreateInput('', 10, 80, 500)
GUICtrlCreateLabel('Strings to find', 10, 110)
$iSearchStrings = GUICtrlCreateEdit('', 10, 130, 500, 200)
GUICtrlCreateLabel('Result', 10, 340)
$iResult = GUICtrlCreateEdit('', 10, 360, 500, 200)
$iButtonSearchPath = GUICtrlCreateButton('...', 520, 27, 25)
$iButtonFilePattern = GUICtrlCreateButton('...', 520, 130, 25)
$iComboSearchExe = GUICtrlCreateCombo('', 520, 360, 100, Default, 0x3); $CBS_DROPDOWNLIST
GUICtrlSetData($iComboSearchExe, _Get_SearchExe(True), $sSearchExe)
$iCheckboxWithStrings = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox('Output no strings', 520, 460)
If $sSearchExe <> 'findstr' Then
    GUICtrlSetState($iCheckboxWithStrings, $GUI_DISABLE)
EndIf
$iButtonSearch = GUICtrlCreateButton('Search', 520, 500, 100, 60)
GUISetState()

GUICtrlSetTip($iFilePatterns, 'i.e. *.txt')
GUICtrlSetTip($iButtonFilePattern, 'Select pattern file to read')
GUICtrlSetTip($iButtonSearchPath, 'Select folder to search')
GUICtrlSetTip($iComboSearchExe, 'Select main search executable')

While 1
    Switch GUIGetMsg()
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit

        Case $iButtonFilePattern
            ; Backup current workdir as FileOpenDialog changes it.
            $sSaveDir = @WorkingDir

            ; Dialog option 1 = File must exist.
            $sSelectedFile = FileOpenDialog('Pattern file containing search strings', _
             '', 'Text files (*.txt)|All files (*.*)', 1, '', $iMainGui _
            )

            If @error Then ContinueLoop
            GUICtrlSetData($iSearchStrings, FileRead($sSelectedFile))
            FileChangeDir($sSaveDir)

        Case $iButtonSearch
            ; Read ctrls and trim ends of whitespace.
            $sFilePatterns = StringStripWS(GUICtrlRead($iFilePatterns), 3)
            $sSearchPath = StringStripWS(GUICtrlRead($iSearchPath), 3)
            $sSearchStrings = StringStripWS(GUICtrlRead($iSearchStrings), 3)

            If $sFilePatterns == '' Then ContinueLoop
            If $sSearchPath == '' Then ContinueLoop
            If $sSearchStrings == '' Then ContinueLoop

            $sStringsFile = _Save_PatternFile($sSearchStrings)
            If @error Then
                MsgBox(0x30, @ScriptName, 'Write temp patterns file error', 0, $iMainGui)
                ContinueLoop
            EndIf

            If GUICtrlRead($iCheckboxWithStrings) = $GUI_CHECKED Then
                $bWithNoStrings = True
            Else
                $bWithNoStrings = False
            EndIf

            $sStdout = _Run_Search($sFilePatterns, $sSearchPath, $sStringsFile, $bWithNoStrings)

            GUICtrlSetData($iResult, $sStdout)

        Case $iButtonSearchPath
            $sSelectedDir = FileSelectFolder('Choose search directory.', _
             '', 0, '', $iMainGui _
            )

            If @error Then ContinueLoop
            GUICtrlSetData($iSearchPath, $sSelectedDir)

        Case $iComboSearchExe
            $sSearchExe = GUICtrlRead($iComboSearchExe)

            Switch $sSearchExe
                Case 'findstr'
                    GUICtrlSetState($iCheckboxWithStrings, $GUI_ENABLE)

                Case Else
                    GUICtrlSetState($iCheckboxWithStrings, $GUI_UNCHECKED)
                    GUICtrlSetState($iCheckboxWithStrings, $GUI_DISABLE)
            EndSwitch
    EndSwitch
WEnd

Exit


Func _Get_SearchExe($bGetComboString = False)
    Local $sComboString, $sSearchExe

    ; Vaild entries to select from.
    If @OSArch = 'X86' Then
        Local $aSearchExe[] = ['findstr', 'strings']
    Else
        Local $aSearchExe[] = ['findstr', 'strings', 'strings64']
    EndIf

    If $bGetComboString Then
        For $sItem in $aSearchExe
            $sComboString &= $sItem & '|'
        Next

        $sComboString = StringTrimRight($sComboString, 1)

        Return $sComboString
    EndIf

    $sSearchExe = IniRead(@ScriptDir & '\searcher.ini', 'Main', 'SearchExe', 'findstr')

    ; Trim .exe from right side.
    If StringRegExp($sSearchExe, '(?i).exe\Z') Then
        $sSearchExe = StringTrimRight($sSearchExe, 4)
    EndIf

    ; Return valid search exe.
    For $sItem in $aSearchExe
        If $sSearchExe = $sItem Then Return $sSearchExe
    Next

    ; Else return default search exe.
    Return 'findstr'
EndFunc


Func _Save_PatternFile($sSearchStrings)
    Local $hWrite, $sStringsFile

    ; Get unique filename for patterns file.
    $sStringsFile = @TempDir & '\searcher1000.tmp'

    For $i1 = 1000 To 10000
        If Not FileExists(@TempDir & '\searcher' & $i1 & '.tmp') Then
            $sStringsFile = @TempDir & '\searcher' & $i1 & '.tmp'
            ExitLoop
        EndIf
    Next

    ; Write file for findstr to get strings from using utf-8 and erase mode.
    $hWrite = FileOpen($sStringsFile, 0x102)
    If $hWrite = -1 Then Return SetError(1, 0, '')
    FileWrite($hWrite, $sSearchStrings & @CRLF)
    FileClose($hWrite)

    Return $sStringsFile
EndFunc


Func _Run_Search($sFilePatterns, $sSearchPath, $sStringsFile = @TempDir & '\searcher1000.tmp', $bWithNoStrings = False)
    Local $iPid, $sCommand, $sStdout
    Dim $sSearchExe

    If Not $sSearchExe Then $sSearchExe = 'findstr'

    ; Build command.
    If StringLeft($sSearchExe, 7) = 'strings' Then
        $sCommand = 'cmd /c ' & $sSearchExe & ' -nobanner -s ' & $sFilePatterns & _
         '|' & 'findstr /l /i /g:"' & $sStringsFile & '"'
    Else
        $sCommand = 'findstr /l /i /s '

        If $bWithNoStrings Then $sCommand &= '/m '

        $sCommand &= '/g:"' & $sStringsFile & '" ' & $sFilePatterns
    EndIf

    ; Run findstr and get stdout (opt_flag = 2).
    $iPid = Run($sCommand, $sSearchPath, @SW_HIDE, 2)

    Do
        Sleep(10)
        $sStdout &= StdoutRead($iPid)
    Until @error

    ; Cleanup tmp file.
    if StringRegExp($sStringsFile, '(?i)searcher\d{4,}\.tmp\Z') Then
        FileDelete($sStringsFile)
    EndIf

    Return $sStdout
EndFunc
```

This is AutoIt v3 code. It does searches recursive using `findstr`.
If no arguments passed then it shows the Gui.
No Gui is shown if arguments are passed and outputs to stdout and stderr.

Compiled and tested as Gui. Could probably compile as Cui which may
be better for CLI use though you may get a console window when the Gui
opens when no arguments are passed.

Supports CLI arguments so it can be used in a CMD script or similar.
Use argument `/?` to see a messagebox showing syntax, arguments
available, descriptions and other useful information.

CLI Syntax is `searcher search_path patternfile filepattern [[filepattern] ... ] [/m]`.

Was not created to do exactly as Hackoo's code does as I was
too lazy to read it. Perhaps similar though different language
used which makes it different to use.
Let me know if a feature is missing and I may update it.

---

Note: I may not list all updated items. Major items expected.

Updated with checkbox control and argument to allow output no strings.
i.e. `filepath:found_string`. That is the format that `findstr` outputs.

Updated to use UTF-8 without BOM for the pattern file read by `findstr`.

Updated to use `findstr`, `strings` or `strings64`. Homepage of [Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings).
Place the stream executables in a directory accessable in PATH.

Comment: Wow, your script is fast like a Flash, but you can do to sure that the text you are looking for is in Result next to the file name. I just have text that can not be in the files.

Comment: Looks like Hackoo is using `find` on each file at a glance while I use `findstr` to pass `*.ext` as is so `findstr` does all the heavy load. The Result edit at bottom of Gui contains the files found that contains the string(s).

Comment: In Result, it prints only the file names. You can make search text next to the name of file?

instead that "Test_Dog.txt" to was it "[My_Cat] Test_Dog.txt".

Comment: Sorry, I understand you now. Like `findstr` without the `/m` argument to also output the search string with the filename. OK, a feature to consider for update. The output would be `filename found_string` as that is what `findstr` outputs. I will look at updating.

Comment: When selecting the "Output with strings" checkbox, he found one file and seems to have stopped searching further. And As a Result, printed only the name of the file with a colon at the end Test_Dog.txt:

Comment: Are you using unicode characters? Perhaps that is the issue. Updated `FileOpen` to use utf-8 without bom. Unsure what format `findstr` can handle other than ASCII.

Comment: Maybe this can help with Unicode? https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/downloads/strings

Comment: Thanks for the *Strings* link. Try the v1.1 update which uses `findstr`, `strings`, or `strings64`.

Comment: When I select strings64 prints what I need. Great work. Thank you.